# Sqlite3 on node.js makes an SQLITE_ERROR

Tags: node.js, sqlite, discord.js

```js
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: '가입',
    aliases: ['면접', '면접보기', '회사입장', '캐스트당함'],
    description: 'CEO봇의 회사에 면접을 봐요(항상 합격당하는 이상한 회사)',
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        let db = new sqlite3.Database('./database.db', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE, (err) => {
            if(err){
                const embed=new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('blue')
                .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setTitle(`데이터베이스를 불러오는데 에러가 있었습니다`)
                .setDescription(`에러 내용: **${err.message}**`)
                message.channel.send(embed)
            } 
        })
        db.run('CREATE TABLE USERS(id text, name text, money int, where int, sawhe int, vip int, black int, present int, nitropresent int, nwemool int, admin int', function(err){
            if(err){
                const embed=new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('blue')
                .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setTitle(`데이터베이스의 테이블을 생성하는데 에러가 있었습니다`)
                .setDescription(`에러 내용: **${err.message}**`)
                message.channel.send(embed)
            }

        })
        db.close((err) => {
            if(err){
                const embed=new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('blue')
                .setFooter(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setTitle(`데이터베이스를 저장(종료)하는데 에러가 있었습니다`)
                .setDescription(`에러 내용: **${err.message}**`)
                message.channel.send(embed)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I'm making a Discord Bot with node.js and is going to use sqlite3 for the database.
That's my code(Please ignore the Korean).
If I run the code on visual studio code, an error `SQLITE_ERROR: near "where": syntax error` happens.
Please answer the question^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that since `where` is one of the restricted words in the SQL syntax, the parser tries to parse the query differently.

Changing `where` to `location` should solve it.

Also, you need to close the bracket at the end of your insert statement.